# how to combine Architecture Components with data binding on android?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I have developed app base on android data binding library: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

```
class SignInViewModel extends BaseObservable {

    @Bindable
    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}
```

and now I want to use ViewModelProviders from new library: 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html

```
SignInViewModel signInViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SignInViewModel.class);
```

How it combine? any idea? or should be combined these two libraries?

**Edit**

I change to:

```
class SignInViewModel extends ViewModel {
   public ObservableField<String> login = new ObservableField<>("");

    public ObservableField<String> password = new ObservableField<>("");
}
```

and now compiles, but question is: is it right way?

Comment: I have found an [article](http://bytes.schibsted.com/data-binding-android-architecture-components-preview/) about this topic. Short answer, there is currently no 'right' way and we may have to wait for some news from the databinding team theirselves.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a known incompatibility. You can't extend `BaseObservable` and `AndroidViewModel` at the same time, so you can't use `@Bindable` making two-way data binding <strike>impossible</strike>*.

This will be fixed after arch components 1.0 final (on the data binding side).

*Edit: You can make your own ObservableViewModel: https://gist.github.com/JoseAlcerreca/4b66f9953d50b483d80e6b9ad7172685

Comment: So as a workaround the solution with using ObservableField is correct approach?

Comment: Yes, if you can restrict to using `ObservableField`s, you're fine.

Comment: Thanks this really saved me, I was switching out my `BaseOverable` view models for `AndroidViewModel` but ran into problems as my app is form heavy and uses a lot or two-way data binding. I made the form fields use `ObservableField` and kept `LiveData` for everything else for the activity to observe.

Comment: @JoseAlcérreca now that Architecture Components are in 1.0 I don't see any differences when it comes to combining them with DataBinding or am I missing something? I can't find anything in the release notes about this at least.

Comment: It's done on the data binding side and it's in the works!

Comment: Hello.. can someone provide a link of sample that uses ViewModel with 2 way data binding as discussed above. Pleaseeee....

Comment: Thanks extending ObservableViewModel class solves my problem awesome

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this didn't exist when when the question was asked, but there is another option explained in this article: https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-observability-9de4ff3fe038

Basically instead of extending from BaseObservable you can **implement** android.databinding.**Observable**.

It's slightly more work as you need to also do the following:

1. Create this variable in your model class

   ```
   private PropertyChangeRegistry registry = new PropertyChangeRegistry();
   ```
2. Implement the overriden methods like this

   ```
   @Override
   public void addOnPropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChangedCallback callback) {
       registry.add(callback);
   }

   @Override
   public void removeOnPropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChangedCallback callback) {
       registry.remove(callback);
   }
   ```
3. Replace all the "BR" calls with these:

   ```
   registry.notifyChange(this, BR.bar);
   ```

Everything else works the same as extending from BaseObservable. So I think maybe this is the solution that Jose might have been alluding to which probably wasn't available back then. It seems to work.

**Update:** As Eugene Brusov has mentioned, you can now use LiveData with data binding. This is what I'm doing now and it's much easier with less boilerplate. See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible with Android Studio 3.1 Canary 6 (https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/12/android-studio-31-canary-6-is-now.html):

> You can now use a LiveData object as an observable field in data binding expressions. The ViewDataBinding class now includes a new setLifecycle method that you need to use to use to observe LiveData objects.

You can find more details and sample in this [Medium post](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-livedata-with-data-binding-7bf85871bbd8).

Answer (score 1):

This can be also solved using a wrapper:

```
class SignInViewModelWrapper extends ViewModel {
    public final SignInViewModel model = new SignInViewModel();
}

class SignInViewModel extends BaseObservable {

    @Bindable
    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}
```

You can then get the view model like this:

```
SignInViewModel signInViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SignInViewModelWrapper.class).model;
```