# Using LiveData with Data Binding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, android-mvvm

With the stabilization of Android Architecture Components I started updating all my basic `ViewModel`s to the new implementation of[`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html). In my understanding, the usage of [`LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html) is recommended to hold the `Model` class since it handles the lifecycle better.

I like using `Data Binding` because it makes the code clearer in Java/Kotlin side and it is not needed to "watch" the value changes to update the UI. However the layout using `Data Binding` only watch data changes if the `Model` (or the ViewModel) extends [`BaseObservable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BaseObservable.html) and `LiveData` does not. I understand the one of the main objectives of `LiveData` is to be observed and updates the UI programmatically but for simple updates, `Data Binding` is very useful.

This issue was already reported ([GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/34#issuecomment-305991529) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077566/how-to-combine-architecture-components-with-data-binding-on-android#comment82259306_44178060)) and first was said that the version 1.0 would have it and now is said that this feature is in development.

In order to use both `LiveData` and `Data Binding`, I created a very simple implementation of class that extends `BaseObservable`:

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData
import android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import android.databinding.BaseObservable

class ObservableMutableLiveData<T>() : BaseObservable() {

    private var data: MutableLiveData<T> = MutableLiveData()

    constructor(data: T) : this() {
        this.data.value = data
    }

    public fun set(value: T) {
        if (value != data.value) {
            data.value = value
            notifyChange()
        }
    }

    public fun get(): T? {
        return data.value
    }

    public fun getObservable(): LiveData<T> {
        return data
    }
}
```

So basically my `ObservableMutableLiveData` is a copy of [`ObservableField`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/c9a5d6f140f732ca0ff279a4b1ee315072e1c422/library/src/main/java/android/databinding/ObservableField.java) using `LiveData` to store the model and with this implementation, the layout updates after every model update.

The questions are:

- Is this a bad implementation of `LiveData`? Does this wrapper "breaks" the functionalities of `LiveData`, such as be lifecycle-aware?
- In my understanding, `LiveData` is the new `ObservableField`. Is this correct?

Comment: The proper way of using data binding with live data is now in the documentation of data binding: [Use LiveData to notify the UI about data changes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture#livedata).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Android Studio 3.1 (currently in Canary 6) will fix this issue, since `LiveData` can be used as `observable field`:

> Updates to Data Binding:
>
> You can now use a LiveData object as an observable field in data binding expressions. The ViewDataBinding class now includes a new setLifecycle method that you need to use to use to observe LiveData objects.

Source: [Android Studio 3.1 Canary 6 is now available](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/12/android-studio-31-canary-6-is-now.html)

Comment: Can you provide an example how to do that?

Comment: @kyurkchyan add this `binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);`
 https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture#java

Answer (score 35):

For those who came across this question looking for an example like I did, here's one:

In layout `.xml` put the `LiveData` element with it's type:

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="myString"
            type="android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData&lt;String&gt;"/>
    </data>

    ...

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text='@{myString}'
        ...
     />

    ...

</layout>
```

In your code set it's value and the lifecycle owner:

```
MutableLiveData<String> myString = new MutableLiveData<>();

...

binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
binding.setMyString(myString);
```

That's it :)

Note that the default value of `LiveData` elements is `null` so assign initial values to make sure you get the desired effect right away or use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46488442/is-it-possible-to-enforce-non-nullability-of-livedata-values/50154853#50154853) to enforce nullability.

**EDIT**:
Use `androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData&lt;String&gt;` as type if you use `androidx`.

Answer (score 1):

For androidx will be:

> androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="myString"
            type="androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData&lt;String&gt;"/>
    </data>

    ...

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text='@{myString}'
        ...
     />

    ...

</layout>
```

And for Kotlin:

```
  val myStr = MutableLiveData<String>()

...

 binding.apply {
            setLifecycleOwner(this)
            this.myString = myStr
        }
```

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer does not give an example. So here's one I've tested and it works.

In layout:

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.abc.xyz.viewmodels.MyViewModel"/>
    </data>

    ...

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text='@{viewmodel.myString}'
        ...
     />

    ...

</layout>
```

In fragment:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, 
         container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val binding: FragmentAlbumBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.fragment_album, container, false)
        binding.apply {
            fragment = this
            viewModel = albumViewModel
            lifecycleOwner = this
    }
}
```