# Unable to bind LiveData List to Spinner entries

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-livedata

I have a Fragment `MyFragment` currently which has a Spinner `my_spinner`. For testing my app, I originally populated the contents of `my_spinner` manually by observing the property `myLiveDataList` in the AndroidViewModel `MyViewModel` as below:

**my_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.fragments.MyFragment">

    <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**MyFragment.kt**

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer

import com.example.app.R
import com.example.app.data.room.entities.MyEntity
import com.example.app.ui.viewmodels.MyViewModel
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.my_fragment.*

class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = MyFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)

        val myAdapter = ArrayAdapter<MyEntity>(this.context!!, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)

        // This is where I populate my_spinner
        viewModel.myLiveDataList.observe(this, Observer<List<MyEntity>> { data ->
            data?.forEach {
                myAdapter.add(it)
            }
        })

        my_spinner.adapter = myAdapter
    }
}
```

**MyViewModel.kt**

```
import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.toLiveData
import com.example.app.data.repositories.MyRepository
import com.example.app.data.room.entities.MyEntity

class MyViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val myRepository = MyRepository(application)

    val myLiveDataList: LiveData<List<MyEntity>>
        get() = myRepository.getAllData().toLiveData()
}
```

This fills `my_spinner` successfully when I navigate to `MyFragment`:

[image: App before making data-binding changes]

Since it populates as expected, I went ahead to make the following changes to `my_fragment.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable name="viewmodel"
                  type="com.example.app.ui.viewmodels.MyViewModel" />
    </data>

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".ui.fragments.MyFragment">

        <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                app:entries="@{viewmodel.myLiveDataList}"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

I've added in a Binding Adapter file `BindingAdapterUtil` (following code was copied from [this article](https://medium.com/fueled-engineering/binding-spinner-in-android-c5fa8c084480)):

```
import android.R
import android.view.View
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Spinner
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter
import androidx.databinding.InverseBindingAdapter
import androidx.databinding.InverseBindingListener
import com.example.app.ui.adapter.SpinnerExtensions.getSpinnerValue
import com.example.app.ui.adapter.SpinnerExtensions.setSpinnerEntries
import com.example.app.ui.adapter.SpinnerExtensions.setSpinnerInverseBindingListener
import com.example.app.ui.adapter.SpinnerExtensions.setSpinnerItemSelectedListener
import com.example.app.ui.adapter.SpinnerExtensions.setSpinnerValue

@BindingAdapter("entries")
fun Spinner.setEntries(entries: List<Any>?) {
    setSpinnerEntries(entries)
}

@BindingAdapter("onItemSelected")
fun Spinner.setItemSelectedListener(itemSelectedListener: SpinnerExtensions.ItemSelectedListener?) {
    setSpinnerItemSelectedListener(itemSelectedListener)
}

@BindingAdapter("newValue")
fun Spinner.setNewValue(newValue: Any?) {
    setSpinnerValue(newValue)
}

@BindingAdapter("selectedValue")
fun Spinner.setSelectedValue(selectedValue: Any?) {
    setSpinnerValue(selectedValue)
}

@BindingAdapter("selectedValueAttrChanged")
fun Spinner.setInverseBindingListener(inverseBindingListener: InverseBindingListener?) {
    setSpinnerInverseBindingListener(inverseBindingListener)
}

@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "selectedValue", event = "selectedValueAttrChanged")
fun Spinner.getSelectedValue(): Any? {
    return getSpinnerValue()
}

object SpinnerExtensions {

    fun Spinner.setSpinnerEntries(entries: List<Any>?) {
        if (entries != null) {
            val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.simple_spinner_item, entries)
            arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            adapter = arrayAdapter
        }
    }

    fun Spinner.setSpinnerItemSelectedListener(listener: ItemSelectedListener?) {
        if (listener == null) {
            onItemSelectedListener = null
        } else {
            onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                    if (tag != position) {
                        listener.onItemSelected(parent.getItemAtPosition(position))
                    }
                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {}
            }
        }
    }

    fun Spinner.setSpinnerInverseBindingListener(listener: InverseBindingListener?) {
        if (listener == null) {
            onItemSelectedListener = null
        } else {
            onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                    if (tag != position) {
                        listener.onChange()
                    }
                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {}
            }
        }
    }

    fun Spinner.setSpinnerValue(value: Any?) {
        if (adapter != null ) {
            val position = (adapter as ArrayAdapter<Any>).getPosition(value)
            setSelection(position, false)
            tag = position
        }
    }

    fun Spinner.getSpinnerValue(): Any? {
        return selectedItem
    }

    interface ItemSelectedListener {
        fun onItemSelected(item: Any)
    }
}
```

And I've modified the `onActivityCreated` in `MyFragment` like so:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)

    DataBindingUtil.setContentView<MyFragmentBinding>(
        this.activity!!, R.layout.my_fragment
    ).apply {
        this.setLifecycleOwner(this@MyFragment)
        this.viewmodel = viewModel
    }
}
```

The result of this is that `my_spinner` is no longer populating with the contents of `MyViewModel.myLiveDataList`. To try to ascertain if the property  was at fault, I created a new property in `MyViewModel` like so:

```
val myList: List<String>?
    get() = listOf("First", "Second", "Third")
```

And I have bound this property to `my_spinner` just like `MyViewModel.myLiveDataList` above with success this time.

The function in `MyRepository.getAllData()` (which `myLiveDataList` returns) returns a `Flowable<List<MyEntity>>` (RxJava), which calls a Room DAO to get the data. My assumption here is that `myLiveDataList` doesn't have anything to serve when it tries to bind the values for the first time, and never tries again.

Am I missing something when trying to bind a LiveData datasource to a Spinner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50246793/4406995), I've modified `my_fragment.xml` to the following:

```
...
<data>
    <import type="java.util.List" />
    <import type="com.example.app.data.room.entities.MyEntity" />
    <import type="androidx.lifecycle.LiveData" />
    <variable name="viewmodel"
              type="com.example.app.ui.viewmodels.MyViewModel" />

    <variable name="myTestList"
              type="LiveData&lt;List&lt;MyEntity&gt;&gt;" />
</data>
...
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:entries="@{myTestList}"/>
...
```

I've also removed the contents of `MyFragment.onActivityCreated` and modified `MyFragment.onCreateView` as followed:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
    val binding = MyFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)
    binding.viewmodel = viewModel
    binding.myTestList = viewModel.myLiveDataList

    return binding.root
}
```

Not a perfect solution, and I still don't know why my original bout at this problem didn't yield the desired results, but it will do. If there is a better way of binding a Spinner to LiveData in this fashion, please let me know.