# Room annotation processor with Data binding

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-room, 2-way-object-databinding, annotation-processor

I have used Data binding in my existing code and now I am migrating to Room for persistence.
I have followed the steps mentioned in  [Florina's Blog](https://medium.com/google-developers/7-steps-to-room-27a5fe5f99b2) for room

My Code builds fine without java code error or BR related error when I remove room dependency

```
 annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0'
```

and its runs too, but gives Runtime exception saying database_Impl does not exists. As it couldn't generate that's file.

But after I put Annotation processor back, it give me

```
 Error:(29, 37) error: cannot find symbol class BR
```

My gradle plugin used is `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1`

They both don't seem to work together

Steps taken so far:

1. Changed BaseObservable to Observable [As suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077566/how-to-combine-architecture-components-with-data-binding-on-android/44178060#44178060)
2. Updated Android Studio to 3.0.1
3. Tried using gradle latest plugin canary 6
4. Clear, Clear Cache also done

Has anyone used Room and Data binding together ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After 4 days of efforts I finally made my code run properly.
Steps to solve the

**Data binding error like**
error: package com.packagename.databinding does not exist
error: cannot find symbol class CustomMainActivityBinding

The app gradle must have below code added in order to view more than 100 errors that come by default

```
allprojects {
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxerrs" << "4000"
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxwarns" << "4000"
    }
  }
}
```

Gradle dependencies for data binding and Room arch components

```
annotationProcessor 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.1'

implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0'
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0'
```

Note: Gradle plugin version is 3.0.1

I changed my all VMs to implement Observable and call

```
registry.notifyChange(this, BR.bar);
```

in case of notify change and also implement overridden methods

```
@Override
public void addOnPropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChangedCallback    
callback) {
registry.add(callback);
}

@Override
public void removeOnPropertyChangedCallback(
OnPropertyChangedCallback callback) {
registry.remove(callback);
}
```

These things made my code Build, but it run without exceptions when I solved the Room query related errors. Which was the main reason, code was building but not running. These errors I could see when I **Rebuid** my project again.

**UPDATE:**

After **Android studio 3.1.3**, ***Message*** window is gone and now all build error  appears under ***Build*** view. Although there is toggle available to get textview response of error, for data-binding errors it isn't sufficient.

Solution that helped me:

1. In Command promt/Terminal navigate to project root.
2. Run this command "./gradlew build --stacktrace" if Mac or ".\gradlew 
   build --stacktrace" if Windows.
3. Now search for "error:" tag and the compile time errors will show up.

I couldn't get these errors in IDE.

Comment: Thanks a lot, You saved my life )))

Comment: What's the registry object that you call?

Comment: @Christian private transient PropertyChangeRegistry registry = new PropertyChangeRegistry();

Comment: ./gradlew build --stacktrace did the trick for me. Android Studio was not showing all errors

Comment: Hello @DeeshaV , I am also facing this problem since yesterday and haven't found the solution yet. I am using androidX that's why I can't use your dependencies. Please help if you have the solution for androidX.

Comment: I had not added Primary key in the Model class that's why error was coming.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the following reasons may cause the error:

1. Incorrect getter/setter (missing or incorrect name)
2. Incorrect return type in Dao
3. annotationProcessor or kapt issues
4. The default constructor is overridden (you need to keep the empty constructor for Room)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue while adding room dependencies. Add this in the below way to resolve the error.

```
 def roomVersion = "2.0.0-rc01"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$roomVersion"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$roomVersion"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$roomVersion"
```