# Error while adding another table in room database

Tags: android, android-room

I already was using room database in my application. Now I have migrated my project to androidX, so dependencies are changed.

Now when I am adding a table and trying to run the project, I am getting an error for multiple files:

```
error: cannot find symbol class BR
```

Here is my model class:

```
@Keep
@Entity
public class Notification {
    private String title;
    private String body;

    public Notification(String title, String body) {
        this.title = title;
        this.body = body;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

Here is my NotificationDao Class:

```
   public abstract class NotificationDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    public abstract void insert(Notification notification);

    @Query("DELETE FROM Notification")
    public abstract void deleteAll();
}
```

Here is the code written for migration:

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Notification (`title` TEXT, `body` TEXT)");
        }
    };
```

I have increased the version from 1 to 2.

I have added this in build as well.

```
    Room.databaseBuilder(
                application,
                MyDatabase.class,
                Configuration.DB_NAME
        ).addMigrations(MyDatabase.MIGRATION_1_2).build();
```

app.gradle is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 211990017
        versionName "2.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        // Write out the current schema of Room
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString(),]
            }
        }
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        project.archivesBaseName = "xxxx";
        multiDexEnabled true
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11 -fexceptions"
                arguments "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang",
                        "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared",
                        "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21"

            }
        }

    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("keystores/xxxx")
            storePassword "xxxx"
            keyAlias "xxxx"
            keyPassword "xxxx"
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles fileTree(dir: "proguard", include: ["*.pro"]).asList().toArray()
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles fileTree(dir: "proguard", include: ["*.pro"]).asList().toArray()
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    flavorDimensions "environment"
    productFlavors {
        development {
            applicationId "com.emproto.xxxx"
            resValue "string", "content_provider", "com.xxx.xxxx.fileprovider"
        }
        production {
            applicationId "com.xxxx"
            resValue "string", "content_provider", "com.xxxx.fileprovider"
        }
    }
    splits {
        // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
        abi {
            // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
            enable true
            // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
            // want APKs for x86 and x86_64.
            // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none.
            reset()
            // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
            include "x86", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a"

            // Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
            universalApk true
        }
    }

}

ext.abiCodes = ['x86': 1, 'x86_64': 2, 'armeabi-v7a': 3, 'arm64-v8a': 4]
import com.android.build.OutputFile
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def baseVersionCode = project.ext.abiCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI))
        if (baseVersionCode != null) {
            output.versionCodeOverride = Integer.valueOf(baseVersionCode + variant.versionCode)
        }
    }
}

ext {
    retrofitVersion = '2.3.0'
    daggerVersion = '2.11'
    supportLibVersion = '28.0.0'
    googleLibVersion = '16.0.1'
    frescoLibVersion = '2.0.0'
    moEngageVersion = '9.8.02'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'

    /*Dagger 2 is a fully static and compile time dependency injection framework*/
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
    implementation 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

    /*LiveData and ViewModel*/
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'

    /*
                annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0"
            */

    /*Room*/
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.3'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.3'

    // Java8 support for Lifecycles
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.2.0'

    /*Retrofit*/
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"

    /*For loading images from network*/
    implementation "com.facebook.fresco:fresco:$frescoLibVersion"
    implementation "com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:$frescoLibVersion"

    /*For the left menu*/
    implementation 'com.yarolegovich:sliding-root-nav:1.1.0'

    /*For the typing indicator*/
    implementation 'com.github.channguyen:adv:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'

    /*For Graphs */
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'

    /*For firebase push notifications */
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6"
    /*For Database debugging */
    //    debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.4'

    /*For S - Health */
    implementation files('libs/s-health/samsung-health-data-v1.3.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/s-health/sdk-v1.0.0.jar')

    /*For Google-Fit */
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:$googleLibVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$googleLibVersion"

    /*Circular floating action bar*/
    implementation 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'

    // For animated GIF support
    implementation "com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:$frescoLibVersion"

    /*Circular seekbar - Feelings*/
    implementation 'com.github.JesusM:HoloCircleSeekBar:v2.2.2'

    /*Circular Layout - Feelings*/
    implementation 'com.github.andreilisun:circular-layout:1.0'

    /*For offline log synchronization*/
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'

    /*Wheel picker - RecordCholesterol*/
    implementation 'com.weigan:loopView:0.1.2'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    /*Image Cropper - Profile Fragment*/
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'

    /*PDF  Viewer - Prescription/Report */
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
    api 'com.thedesigncycle.ui:views:0.3.1'
    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.11.0'
    implementation files('libs/omron/jp.co.omron.healthcare.omoron_connect.wrapper-1.3.jar')
    implementation 'com.appsee:appsee-android:+'
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:viewtooltip:1.1.6'
    implementation 'com.asksira.android:cameraviewplus:0.9.5'
    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.3.1'

    implementation 'com.priyankvex:smarttextview:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.flipkart-incubator:android-inline-youtube-view:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.varunest:sparkbutton:1.0.6'

    implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:3.2.0'




    //foo transitions in trel home(doctor names)
    implementation "com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.8.1"

    //AppsFlyer
    implementation 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.10.3'
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'

    //picasso image loading lib
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    //Facebook analytics dependency
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

    //Moengage dependency
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "com.moengage:moe-android-sdk:$moEngageVersion"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

How can the error be fixed?

Comment: **cannot find symbol class BR** is related to *data binding*. Can you add your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: When I am just removing the new table, the app is working fine.

Comment: I have updated the question and added the app.gradle file.

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48356496/room-annotation-processor-with-data-binding but not getting help.

Answer (score 0):

Not adding the primary key in model class was causing the problem. I think more specific error messages should be there from android studio's side regarding room database.